# List (nav) items wont stretch over div that is floated right

Tags: css, html, menu, z-index, nav

I am currently trying to get a horizontal navigation menu to stretch from across the whole of my container.

The div that it is in stretches across fine, but the actual list items don't and I am unsure why.

The CSS for the right hand bar, the container holding the nav bar, and the nav items is:

```
#rhs{
position: relative;
float: right;

height: 720px;
width: 200px;

background-color: #3D0099;
border-left:2px solid #616161;
}

nav{
display: block;
position: relative;

width: 1010px;
height: 50px;

margin-left: 7px;

background-color: #F0F0F0;

border-top: 1px solid #616161; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #616161; 

z-index: 99999;
 }

 nav li{
list-style: none;
display: inline;

margin-left: 10px;

z-index: 99999;
}
```

The full jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zDzLs/

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, I meant a div that I have placed on the right hand side of my container

Comment: Can you describe what you are going for in more detail, I don't get what your problem  is.

Comment: I wanted to get my menu items to stretch right across my container, but for some reason, the div that I had floated to the right hand side was stopping that happening - they stopped when they got to the boundary of the right hand div. The question has now been answered tho, thank you anyway, and sorry for not being clear. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change css of rhs div to:

```
#rhs{

position: absolute;
right:0px;
height: 720px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #3D0099;
border-left:2px solid #616161;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code was making my OCD go crazy.

I've revised it a bit for you here. Hope you like it.

http://jsfiddle.net/zDzLs/3/

```
<header>

        <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="images/header.png"/></a>

        <nav>
            <ul>
             <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">What is Counselling?</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Personal Counselling</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Relationship Counselling</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Supervision of Counsellors</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Life Coaching</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="content-left"><div class="inner">LEFT</div></div>
        <div class="content-right"><div class="inner">RIGHT</div></div>

    </div>


* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    font: 14px Century Gothic;
}

header {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

header .logo {
    width: 300px;
}

nav {
    background: #F0F0F0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li.active a {
    background: #666;
}


.container {
    margin: 30px auto 0;
    width: 960px; /* 958px */
    border:2px solid #616161;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
}

.content-left {
    float: left;
    width:628px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

.content-right {
    float:left;
    width: 300px;
    background: #f9f9f9
}

.inner {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will properly have a look at this later, and tidy up my code. Much appreciated!